# MODIFICAR DEFAULT_NETWORK_THREAD_POOL_SIZE DE VOLLEY

Tags: java, android-studio, android-volley, volley

Me gustaria cambiar el valor de DEFAULT_NETWORK_THREAD_POOL_SIZE que tiene por defecto volley pero al ser parte de una librería no puedo modificarlo a mi gusto y quisiera saber si alguien lo ha hecho antes y como podría hacerlo. Muchas gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Me imagino que deseas aumentarlo, ¿para que deseas cambiarlo?

Comment: En el [código fuente de Volley](https://github.com/google/volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/RequestQueue.java#L107), la constante `DEFAULT_NETWORK_THREAD_POOL_SIZE` está declarada como `private static final` ... creo que el tipo de declaración es sugestivo. Dicho en lenguaje llano, es un dato definido en la clase con la intención de que no cambie. ¿Puedes cambiarlo? Quizá, pero la pregunta es ¿por qué, para qué? Quizá tendrás que recurrir a algún procedimiento algo oscuro para cambiarla y eso puede afectar seriamente el funcionamiento de `Volley`.